# HtmlUnit ClassCastException while selecting form button

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a form - https://racky.wufoo.com/forms/m1wv5fg40e46lwk/

I am trying to use HtmlUnit to fill the form.

*This is my code -*

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://racky.wufoo.com/forms/m1wv5fg40e46lwk/");
HtmlSubmitInput button = page.getElementByName("saveForm");
HtmlTextInput field1 = page.getElementByName("Field1");
HtmlTextInput field2 = page.getElementByName("Field4");
field1.setValueAttribute("test_test");
field2.setValueAttribute("packpack");
HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

But when I am executing it I get the following error at **HtmlSubmitInput button** line -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImageInput cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput
```

What should I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page.getElementByName("saveForm");
```

Your problem is because this return a HtmlImageInput in your case.
Change your code like this:

```
HtmlInput button = page.getElementByName("saveForm");
```

Comment: I just now checked the HtmlUnit java docs and figured that out! What I did is same as you answered. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Then please approve the answer.

Comment: And it's an `HtmlImageInput` because the element has `type="image"`: `<input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="image" src="" alt="Submit">`.

Comment: @qlown That explains it. Thanks :) .Sorry for the late reply I somehow missed the notification.